# Error to get native android icon from androi.jar

Tags: android, resources, icons, public

hi guys when i would like to get native icon menu from android.jar i get back this error:

```
Resource is not public. (at 'icon' with value '@android:drawable/ic_menu_home').
```

there are some ways to use this icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can copy it to your project's drawable folder. It's located in `<sdk path>\platforms\android-?\data\res\drawable-????\`

Comment: I know already but as with other icons like this "@android:drawable/ic_menu_save" works so I was wondering if there a way to use directly from android.jar even if they aren't public

Comment: you can access it as `@*android:drawable/ic_menu_home` but it isn't really a good idea, cause resource being not public means it can be removed at some point in the future or isn't available on some devices.

Answer (score 1):

Already discussed alot about this stuff: 
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/dabbe62aa1b54c13?pli=1